# How do I add priority fees to a transaction using web3.js?

Tags: web3.js, priority-fees

In @solana/web3.js you'd normally [make a transfer SOL transaction](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol) with `SystemProgram.transfer()`:

```
const transferTransaction = new Transaction().add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: lamportsToSend,
  })
);

await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTransaction, [fromKeypair]);
```

The options for an instruction are defined by [TransferParams](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/TransferParams.html) - right now `TransferParams` doesn't have any options for priority fees.

**How do I send a transaction with priority fees with @solana/web3.js?**

Answer (score 5):

**Answering my own question to help others**

Priority fees are a seperate instruction added to the transaction. See the [Solana Cookbook Priority Fees](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction)

From their example:

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ 
  units: 1000000 
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
  microLamports: 1 
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
.add(modifyComputeUnits)
.add(addPriorityFee)
.add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    })
```